# JSCH print System.err message on textview

Tags: android-studio, jsch

**I have solved this:
My solution:
I print ErrStream into 'in2' and then print it out just like  'in'**

```
InputStream in2 = ((ChannelExec) channel).getErrStream();
```

My goal:

-To print Error message "bash: dumper: command not found" (as shown on android monitor) from System.err on textview

My Question:

-How can I read the Error message from System.err?

What is the code for:

-get ssh commands from user then display as what is it return

---

```
public void ssh_send_cmd(String input_cmd) {
        ssh_input_cmd = input_cmd;
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                IDList.clear();
                Connection connection = null;
                Session session= null;
                try {
                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                // Get SSH session
                session = jsch.getSession(Global.servUser, Global.host, Global.port);
                session.setPassword(Global.servPwd);
                java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
                // Never automatically add new host keys to the host file
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setConfig(config);
                // Connect to remote server
                session.connect();
                System.out.println("Connection through ssh established!");
                String command = ssh_input_cmd;
                Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
                ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
                ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
                InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
                System.out.println("Connect to session...");
                channel.connect();
                
                byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
                while (true) {
                    while (in.available() > 0) {
                        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                        if (i < 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                        update_monitor(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                    }
                    if (channel.isClosed()) {
                        System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                        update_monitor("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                        System.out.println(ee);
                    }
                }
                channel.disconnect();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                update_monitor("error 1");
            }finally{
                if(session !=null && session.isConnected()){
                    session.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
    mythread.start();
}
```

Android Monitor:

> com.example.acer.ssh_cmd I/System.out: Connection through ssh established!
>
> com.example.acer.ssh_cmd I/System.out: Connect to session...
>
> com.example.acer.ssh_cmd W/System.err: ***bash: dumper: command not found***
>
> com.example.asus.ssh_cmd I/System.out: exit-status: 127

bash: dumper:command not found

For your information: "dumper" is input from user and the command is not found